# How to 'require' .js files using npm's scripts config in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying out a node.js library called `pkg` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg), and received the following error:

> Warning Cannot resolve 'path.join(__dirname, './some/file.js')'
>     /path/to/index.js
>     Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file
>     is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.
>     Use a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it
>     as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.

How exactly do you specify a 'resolved file name' in the package.json file? And more generally, is there a way I can specify a path to a file in the package.json file and then just use `require('key in the scripts object')` to use that file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this was to package my code as npm modules and then require them with `npm install xxx --save`.

Then `pkg` works very well in creating executables.